Effect of temperature on voltage of a galvanic cell can't use Nernst equation?
Is it worth investigating the effect of temperature on EMF in a galvanic cell? I suspect the change will be very very small and maybe impossible to test precisely in a high school lab. 
This article said the variation of E with temperature can be find with E(T2)=E(T1)+dE/dT(T2-T1) where dE/dT=R/nF (lnQ) but how is this different to using the Nernst equation?

TL;DR; version:
Testing the EMF dependence on temperature does make sense,  because it is not the matter just of the term $\dfrac{RT}{nF} \ln {Q}$. But you cannot use the Nernst equation directly as it does not explicitly enumerate the temperature dependence of standard reduction potentials.
The derivative of $\text{EMF}$ by absolute temperature depends on:

the current component thermodynamic activities(concentrations,pressures, fugacities) ($\dfrac{RT}{nF} \ln {Q}$)
the reaction entropy ( $\Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}$)
the difference of the heat capacity of products and reactants ($\Delta C_p$)


Detailed evaluation:
\begin{align}
\text{EMF}(T) &= \Delta E^{\circ}(T) - \frac{RT}{nF} \ln{Q} =\\
&= - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} G^{\circ}(T)}{nF} - \frac{RT}{nF} \ln{Q} =\\
&= - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} G^{\circ}(T) + RT \ln{Q}  }{nF}\\
&= - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} H^{\circ}(T)  - T \left( \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}(T) - R \ln{Q}\right)  }{nF}\\
&\approx - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} H^{\circ}_{T_1} +\Delta C_p(T - T_1)  - T \left( \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}_{T_1} + \Delta C_p \ln {\frac{T}{T_1}} - R \ln{Q}\right)  }{nF} \tag{1}
\end{align}
The key influence has the parameter $\Delta C_p$, what is the difference between the total heat capacity of reaction products and reactants. The approximation in the last step assumes constant molar heat capacities of involved components. If such a condition is not met, things would get complicated because of the need of integration of the functions $\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\Delta C_p(T)\text{d}T}$ and $\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\dfrac{\Delta C_p (T)}{T}\text{d}T}$
$$\frac{\text{d}(\text{EMF}(T))}{\text{d}T} \approx -\frac 1{nF} \left( \Delta C_p  - \left( \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}_{T_1} + \Delta C_p \ln {\frac{T}{T_1}} - R \ln{Q}\right) - T \left(  \frac{\Delta C_p }{ T}  \right) \right)= \\
= \frac 1{nF} \left(   \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}_{T_1} + \Delta C_p \ln {\frac{T}{T_1}} - R \ln{Q}\right)  \tag{2} \label{2}$$
In the case where $\Delta C_p \approx 0$, the equation gets simplified to:
\begin{align}
\text{EMF}(T) =  - \frac{\Delta_\text{r} H^{\circ}_{T_1} - T \left( \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}_{T_1} - R \ln{Q}\right)  }{nF} \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$\frac{\text{d}(\text{EMF}(T))}{\text{d}T} = \frac 1{nF} \left(   \Delta_\text{r} S^{\circ}_{T_1}  - R \ln{Q}\right) \tag{4} $$
As the direct conclusion of the equation \eqref{2} comes the TL;DR; answer.

Would it be valid instead of using the textbook iteration of the Nernst equation I use the quotient of the ionic activity constants instead of the equilibrium constant? I'm thinking of making a linear trend of the theoretical and see the correlation between that and the experimental values.

I am not sure what you mean. You can go further and replace the standard reaction Gibbs energy by the -RT ln K, but then you may have trouble to express K = f(T).

Remind me: can you use Le Chatelier's principle to predict how EMF changes with temperature?

It can be, qualitatively. Quantitatively, you can use van't Hoff equation d(ln K)/dT = Delta_r H/(RT^2).

Is it possible/good for me to calculate the theoretical d(EMF(T))/dT = (ΔH - ΔG)/nFT then compare this with my experimental d(EMF(T))/dT? Is this (http://home.moravian.edu/public/chem/public_html/daniell%20cell.pdf) an example of the proper literature values of ΔH and ΔG?
